# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 33 -PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
declare
type nt_type is table of number;
nt nt_type:= nt_type (8038036,8088810);
begin
for i in 1..nt.count
loop
    Insert query
End loop;
End;
```

Above is a query which I'm passing in my Excel sheet and I'm getting the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550 -PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Comment: What is `Insert query`, exactly? I don't know Java nor I pass queries to Excel, but that piece of code looks *wrong* from my Oracle-ish point of view.

Comment: @Littlefoot: Insert Query would be on this kind:- INSERT INTO table_name (nt(i), column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...); where nt(i) is the argument in which above values i.e.(8038036,8088810) are passed

Comment: In that case, please, post what you really used, not such a dummy statement. As the rest of code you posted works OK (as far as Oracle is concerned), I suspect INSERT is a culprit but I can't guess why unless I see it.

Comment: Also if u consider the error msg it says java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 33 which says Line 2:- "type nt_type is table of number;" is expecting  . , ( , @, ;

Comment: That's not what you initially posted. Please (once again, and for the last time), post exact code you used and exactly how Oracle responded.

Comment: What is the connection between Excel and JDBC? Are you just generating the query in Excel and copying it to another client to run - and if so, which one? With the line/character number being reported, it looks like whatever you are using doesn't understand PL/SQL and is treating the first two lines - everything up to the first semicolon - as a complete statement. If you run just those two lines you get the same error.